# Lyx two columns with unequal lengths

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

I'm writing a document in Hebrew, in which the third page is the table of contents (TOC). There are too many items in the TOC, so they fill more than one page:

[image]

I want to "compress" all the items to fill only one page using the multicol function:

[image]

and this is the result after compilation:

[image]

As can be seen - the items in the TOC are equally distributed between the two columns, which have equal lengths. I want to change that, so that the right column will fill the entire length of the page (top to bottom), and the left column will have only the remaining items. Namely, I want the right column to be longer than the left one.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

I added the

Answer (score 2):

So, the solution is more simple than I thought. I just added a star next to the command of the column:

[image]

and the result was exactly as I wanted:

[image]

problem is solved!